# ActionBarSherlock FragmentTabs change implementation to use FragmentActivity instead of Fragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I was digging a lot in the internet about the best way which I can implement ActionBarSherlock in my application so I can stick around with the new Android UI. I've changed my app's whole logic to use FragmentActivity's with nested Fragments, but I need to use TabHost at bottom of my app too. The Launcher activity of my app is extending `TabActivity` which is deprecated I know, but for now that's the best option for me...and don't forget that not everything depends on my choice when it's about building an app and how it should look like. So I found a way how to integrate the Fragments in my app and I find a nice example how to use ABS with Tabs and Fragments on that link : [FragmentTabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java).

But the problem which I am facing in this implementation is that I want to set `FragmentActivity` as content of the different tabs, not `Fragment`, but I couldn't figure it out how to do this. So any kind of help or suggestions or advices or even example are really welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There is only one Activity active at a time. Since your topmost Activity would be your TabActivity everything that should be shown in there is either a view or a fragment. Activities simply can't be nested.

Using the ActionBar you should think about switching to it completely (including the built-in tabs) instead of using the old-fashioned TabHost.

Comment: If it was depending on me there wouldn't be any tabs, but the choice is not mine

Comment: Is any of the possibilities [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/#introduction) offers a solution for you? There are Tabs with Icons. Perhaps you could use them instead.